# How can I find the beam voltage for a Ka band extended interaction oscillator which gives 1 kW output power?

Tags: power, amplifier, circuit-design, rf, oscillator

I want to design an extended interaction oscillator (EIO) working with Ka band which gives us 1 kW output power. The picture below gives the parameters.
I am unable to calculate the beam voltage for this EIO.

The formula relating output power and beam voltage is uploaded. If Power "P" is 1 kW, what will be the beam voltage. I face problem, dealing with the Perveance term.

[image]

[image: output power-beam voltage relation]

Comment: You should explain why you are unable to calculate the beam voltage. I'm not saying I can help but, as it stands, there is really no way anyone can help without understanding the specific problem you are having trouble with.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome! KW = kelvinwatt. kW = kilowatt.